# Switch statement behavior at recyclerView when paginate

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, switch-statement, adapter

**I'm working on a market app and at the orders history activity I have to check for order status so at my adapter I make a switch statement to handle it and it works very well
but when I scroll down and the second page called and adapter list update all status changes **
here's my adapter

```
public class OrdersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private static final int ITEM = 0;
private static final int LOADING = 1;
Context context;
List<Orders> ordersList = new ArrayList<>();
private boolean isLoaderVisible = false;
public int selectedPosition;
IClickRecyclerAdapter clickListener;


public OrdersAdapter(Context context, List<Orders> ordersList) {
    this.context = context;
    if (ordersList != null)
        this.ordersList = new ArrayList<>(ordersList);
    selectedPosition = -1;

}

public void setClickListener(IClickRecyclerAdapter clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    switch (viewType) {
        case ITEM:
            viewHolder = getViewHolder(parent, inflater);
            break;
        case LOADING:
            View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_loading, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new LoadingVH(v2);
            break;
    }
    return viewHolder;
}

@NonNull
private RecyclerView.ViewHolder getViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, LayoutInflater inflater) {
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
    ItemOrderModefiedBinding binding = ItemOrderModefiedBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
    viewHolder = new MainViewHolder(binding);
    return viewHolder;
}

@SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Orders orders = ordersList.get(position);


    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case ITEM:
            OrdersAdapter.MainViewHolder mainViewHolder = (OrdersAdapter.MainViewHolder) holder;
            if (orders.getStatus() != null) {
                mainViewHolder.binding.orderId.setText(orders.getId().toString());


                String givenDateString = orders.getCreatedAt();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

                try {
                    Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
                    long timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    CharSequence ago =
                            DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(timeInMilliseconds, now, DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
                    mainViewHolder.binding.date.setText(ago);

                } catch (ParseException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                switch (orders.getStatus()) {

                    case "request":
                        mainViewHolder.binding.line1.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.grayModefied));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.line2.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.grayModefied));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.line3.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.grayModefied));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.requestedText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mainViewHolder.binding.step1Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.purple_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.step2Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.gray_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.step3Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.gray_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.step4Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.gray_circle));

                        break;
                    case "approve":
                        mainViewHolder.binding.line1.setProgress(100,true);
                        mainViewHolder.binding.line1.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.greencolor));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.line2.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.grayModefied));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.line3.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.grayModefied));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.step1Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.green_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.step2Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.green_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.step3Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.gray_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.step4Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.gray_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.approvedText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        break;
                    case "shipping":
                        mainViewHolder.binding.line1.setProgress(100,true);
                        mainViewHolder.binding.line1.setIndicatorColor(context.getColor(R.color.orange));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.line1.postOnAnimationDelayed(() -> {
                            mainViewHolder.binding.line2.setProgress(100,true);
                            mainViewHolder.binding.line2.setIndicatorColor(context.getColor(R.color.orange));
                        },900);
                        mainViewHolder.binding.step1Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.orange_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.step2Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.orange_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.step3Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.orange_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.step4Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.gray_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.shippingText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case "deliver":
                        mainViewHolder.binding.line1.setProgress(100,true);
                        mainViewHolder.binding.line1.setIndicatorColor(context.getColor(R.color.greencolor));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.line1.postOnAnimationDelayed(() -> {
                            mainViewHolder.binding.line2.setProgress(100,true);
                            mainViewHolder.binding.line2.setIndicatorColor(context.getColor(R.color.greencolor));
                        },900);

                        mainViewHolder.binding.line2.postOnAnimationDelayed(() -> {
                            mainViewHolder.binding.line3.setProgress(100,true);
                            mainViewHolder.binding.line3.setIndicatorColor(context.getColor(R.color.greencolor));
                        },1800);

                        mainViewHolder.binding.step1Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.green_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.step2Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.green_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.step3Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.green_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.step4Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.green_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.deliveredText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case "cancel":
                        mainViewHolder.binding.line1.setProgress(100,true);
                        mainViewHolder.binding.line1.setIndicatorColor(context.getColor(R.color.redcolor));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.line1.postOnAnimationDelayed(() -> {
                            mainViewHolder.binding.line2.setProgress(100,true);
                            mainViewHolder.binding.line2.setIndicatorColor(context.getColor(R.color.redcolor));
                        },900);

                        mainViewHolder.binding.line2.postOnAnimationDelayed(() -> {
                            mainViewHolder.binding.line3.setProgress(100,true);
                            mainViewHolder.binding.line3.setIndicatorColor(context.getColor(R.color.redcolor));
                        },1800);

                        mainViewHolder.binding.step1Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.red_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.step2Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.red_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.step3Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.red_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.step4Circle.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.red_circle));
                        mainViewHolder.binding.deliveredText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mainViewHolder.binding.deliveredText.setText(R.string.cancel);
                        break;

                }

            }

            if (clickListener != null) {
                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                    if (selectedPosition != position) {
                        if (clickListener != null) {
                            clickListener.onClickAdapter(position);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            break;
        case LOADING:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ordersList != null ? ordersList.size() : 0;
}

protected class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ItemOrderModefiedBinding binding;

    public MainViewHolder(@NonNull ItemOrderModefiedBinding itemView) {
        super(itemView.getRoot());
        binding = itemView;
    }

}

protected class LoadingVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public LoadingVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
public Orders getOrders(int position) {
    return ordersList.get(position);
}


public void addItems(List<Orders> orders) {
    this.ordersList.addAll(orders);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return (position == ordersList.size() - 1 && isLoaderVisible)? LOADING : ITEM;
}

//-----------------------------
public void add(Orders orders) {
    ordersList.add(orders);
    notifyItemInserted(ordersList.size() - 1);
}

public void addAll(List<Orders> mcList) {
    for (Orders mc: mcList) {
        add(mc);
    }
}

public void remove(Orders orders) {
    int position = ordersList.indexOf(orders);
    if (position > -1) {
        ordersList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}

public void clear() {
    isLoaderVisible = false;
    ordersList.clear();
    while (getItemCount() > 0) {
        remove(getItem(0));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return getItemCount() == 0;
}

public void addLoadingFooter() {
    isLoaderVisible = true;
    add(new Orders());
}

public void removeLoadingFooter() {
    isLoaderVisible = false;

    int position = ordersList.size() - 1;
    Orders item = getItem(position);
    if (item != null) {
        ordersList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position,ordersList.size());
    }
}

public Orders getItem(int position) {
    return ordersList.get(position);
}
```

}

and this is my fragment

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    binding = FragmentAllOrdersBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View view = binding.getRoot();

    binding.ordersRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    binding.progressLoadingData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ordersViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(OrdersViewModel.class);
    adapter = new OrdersAdapter(context, null);

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
    binding.ordersRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new PaginationListener(linearLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        protected void loadMoreItems() {
            isLoading = true;
            currentPage += 1;
            if (currentPage <= TOTAL_PAGES) {
                adapter.addLoadingFooter();
                Log.d("TTTT", "loadMoreItems: " + currentPage + "  " + TOTAL_PAGES);
                new Handler().postDelayed(() -> loadNextPage(), 500);

            } else {
                isLastPage = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected int getTotalPages() {
            return TOTAL_PAGES;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLastPage() {
            return isLastPage;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLoading() {
            return isLoading;
        }
    });
    new Handler().postDelayed(this::loadFirsPage, 500);


    binding.ordersRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

    binding.ordersRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.setClickListener(position -> {
        Orders orders = adapter.getItem(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleOrderActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constant.EXTRA_ORDER_ID, orders.getId());
        startActivity(intent);

    });

    return view;
}

private void loadFirsPage() {
    ordersViewModel.getCurrentOrders(currentPage);


    ordersViewModel.ordersMutableLiveData.observe(this, orders -> {
        binding.progressLoadingData.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (orders.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
            if(isLoading){
                adapter.removeLoadingFooter();
                isLoading = false;
            }
            if (orders.getData().getData().isEmpty()) {
                binding.emptyState.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } else {
                binding.ordersRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            adapter.addItems(orders.getData().getData());
            TOTAL_PAGES = orders.getData().getLastPage();

            if (currentPage != TOTAL_PAGES) {
            } else {
                if (orders.getData().getLastPage() != 1) {
                    isLastPage = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void loadNextPage() {
    ordersViewModel.getCurrentOrders(currentPage);


}
```

and this screen shoot at first call
[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OXHj.jpg)

and this is after scroll to next page

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBHpu.jpg)

Comment: You can try with  binding.ordersRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);, It wont update its view when you scroll down.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work @Shvet

Comment: What I did to fix this well is to handle all statements at if and else
I figure it out that at adapter if you put if statement you have to make else also to prevent this strange behave when scrolling